# React Query resends request after unfocusing React TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce, react-query

Recently I've tried to create my own component using [React Query](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/) with [TinyMCE for React](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/), but I noticed that **every time I loose focus from TinyMCE editor's text area my request from React Query is sent again** even though nothing has changed in my components (at least I think there is no need for rerender of the component).

*Here you can see that every time I click into editor and after that outside of the editor the request is sent*

[image: Here you can see that every time I click into editor and after that outside of the editor the request is sent]

I created [project to simulate the problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-react-tinymce-twd0nt?file=/index.js). You can see that every time you focus *and* unfocus from the text area of the TinyMCE editor the request from React Query is sent. I tried to use `useEffect` to know if the provided callback is called multiple times as well, but the `useEffect` works as expected.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {
  QueryClient,
  QueryClientProvider,
  useQuery
} from "@tanstack/react-query";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { Editor } from "@tinymce/tinymce-react";

export default function MyEditor() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Editor />
    </div>
  );
}

const fetchData = async () => {
  console.log("Fetching data", new Date());

  return await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1").then((d) =>
    d.json()
  );
};

function App() {
  useQuery(["api"], fetchData);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("This is going to be logged only once");
  }, []);

  return (
    <form>
      <h1>My editor</h1>
      <MyEditor />
    </form>
  );
}

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("container")).render(
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <App />
  </QueryClientProvider>
);
```

These are my package versions:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@tanstack/react-query": "4.3.9",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "4.2.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because the editor renders an `iframe`, you can use the [refetchOnWindowFocus](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/window-focus-refetching#disabling-per-query) option to avoid refetching:

```
useQuery(["api"], fetchData, { refetchOnWindowFocus: false })
```

or perhaps using the method to ignore iframe focus described in the same [doc page](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/window-focus-refetching#ignoring-iframe-focus-events)

It works on codesandbox

Comment: what you can also do is set a `staleTime` for your resource, as only stale queries will be refetched on window focus. `staleTime` defaults to zero, so everything is instantly stale. You'll find that if you mark your resource as fresh for some time via `staleTime` there will also be no refetch in that time frame even if refetchOnWindowFocus is turned on.